# Display notification in Google Chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am just experimenting with the Notification API in web browsers...I want to display a simple notification to the user.

```
if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
  console.log('requesting permission for notifications'); // 1
  Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
    if (result === 'denied') {
      console.log('Permission wasn\'t granted. Allow a retry.'); // 2
      return;
    }
    if (result === 'default') {
      console.log('The permission request was dismissed.');
      return;
    }

  });
}
```

right now, statements 1 and 2 are logged. But I never seen any dialog whatsoever. How can I enabled notifications for a certain URL?

Is there a way to programmatically enable notifications for a URL?

Comment: Your question doesn't explain why you tagged it with google-chrome-extension tag. Can you give more context?

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to create notification in chrome ext. so please refer following code/document.

```
chrome.notifications.create('go ahead', {
        title: 'notification title',
        message: 'my notification message',
        type: 'basic',
        iconUrl: 'https://material.io/icons/static/images/icons-180x180.png'
      },
      function () {
        console.log('notification callback fired.');
      });
```

Add permission in Manifist.Json

```
"permissions": [
   "notifications"
],
```

> Make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page too
>   refer this document for more details
>   https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications